# How R's parallel package would handle 12th Gen Efficiency Cores?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I was planning to do a desktop build with an i7-12700, I mostly need it for high CPU usage R tasks and most of the time parallel processing comes into play.
But I wonder how the new Efficiency Cores in 12th Gen Intel processors handle this task. I am not an expert on hardware/architecture so the question might sound stupid, but my concerns are the following.

1. Suppose I have a task that I want to split over 8 cores, How do I ensure that the task would be run on the performance cores, or is this automatically handled by the OS?
2. In general with other CPUs I usually set the mc.cores = Number of cores on the machine, Is this the correct way or should we put the number of threads there?

So basically might there be a concern choosing the new 12th gen CPU with efficiency cores over 11th Gen CPU say i7-12700 over i7-11700?

***Update***

So I bought the i7-12700 and tested it myself.

**First I tested the default loading order of parallel jobs using code below and by increasing the num_cores from 8 to all the way to 20**

And the order came out to be **1st thread of each performance core > efficiency core thread > second thread of each performance core when first is loaded already**

```
library(parallel)
partask <- function(x) for(idx in 1:x) a<-idx
num_cores <- 8
mclapply(rep(5(10^8),num_cores),partask,mc.cores=num_cores)
```

**Then I specifically put one thread from each of the performance cores under load using R script below**

```
writeLines("for(idx in 1:(10^11)) a<-idx","sclong.R")
for(thread in c(2*(0:7))) system(paste0("taskset -c ",thread," Rscript sclong.R"),ignore.stdout=TRUE,wait=FALSE)
```

**And then benchmarked a task on first a free thread from a performance core and then on a efficiency core thread using code**

```
writeLines("task <- function(x) for(idx in 1:(x)) a<-idx ; microbenchmark::microbenchmark(task(10^7))","scsmall.R")
system("taskset -c 1 Rscript scsmall.R")
system("taskset -c 16 Rscript scsmall.R")
```

**The result was**

```
> system("taskset -c 1 Rscript scsmall.R")
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 task(10^7) 406.9761 416.4491 426.7444 419.0301 437.0794 464.5673   100
> system("taskset -c 16 Rscript scsmall.R")
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 task(10^7) 422.1205 427.8711 436.172 430.5203 443.5989 463.9686   100
```

**So contrary to the default loading order, if all threads on performance cores had been loaded first and then move to the efficiency core's threads, it would have been more efficient.**

So providing the ***affinity.list*** parameter to mclapply can be useful in some specific cases.

Comment: What OS will you be employing?

Comment: Linux, Specifically Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Processor affinity

Depending upon your operating system, you can tell the OS to not use (or deprioritize) certain cores for certain processes. This is typically referred to as processor affinity. [Here is some discussion of why you might (not) want to do this.](https://superuser.com/questions/181577/what-is-windows-priority-and-affinity-and-what-advatanges-does-it-provide) The `parallel` package [appears to have a built-in function to do this directly from R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mcaffinity.html), although [beware incorrect indexing of the cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219228/is-it-possible-in-r-parallelmcparallel-to-limit-the-number-of-cores-used-at).

#### Windows

You can assign specific processes to specific cores in Windows using the Processor Affinity options. [Here's an example of how to do this](https://winbuzzer.com/2020/07/03/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-in-windows-10-with-task-manager-or-system-properties-xcxwbt/).

#### Apple

[Here's basically the same question for Apple operating systems.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419758/how-to-execute-terminal-command-on-energy-efficient-cores-on-m1-chip)

#### Linux

No experience with this but [here's discussion of how to do it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-set-the-processor-affinity-of-a-process-on-linux).

## Number of cores/threads

"Should" in this case is very subjective and so best avoided in questions. However, I'll take a stab: in many cases, "should" is precluded by "cannot" do so with respect to multithreading. I recommend [reading this](https://towardsdatascience.com/parallelization-caveats-in-r-1-the-basics-multiprocessing-and-multithreading-performance-eb584b7e850e) for discussion of multi-threading and multi-processing and how to do it (in R). Note that independent of this, many recommend specifying at least 1 core less than the total number of cores on your personal machine to avoid possible crashed or massive degradation of ability to get other stuff done while R is chugging away.

Comment: So without explicitly setting the affinity, any parallel process would randomly assigned on performance cores and efficiency cores? Assuming all cores are free at that time

Comment: No, it depends on MANY factors. Whether a core is "free" is also not binary. If you really want learn how scheduling works, the best place to start is reading all documentation for all parallel processing packages in R or picking up a textbook:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/3319265784